Reactivecircus emulator crashes with IllegalArgumentException for front camera
I am trying to do some UI testing on github, one of those tests uses camera, front one. This is step that I use for running emulator and runing script
  - name: run tests
    uses: reactivecircus/android-emulator-runner@v2
    with:
      api-level: 29
      disable-animations: true
      profile: Nexus 5X
      emulator-options: -no-snapshot -no-window -no-boot-anim -camera-front emulated
      script: ./.github/workflows/script.sh

That test works fine on my device and on my emulator, but once I run this with reactivecircus emulator, it crashes
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No available output size is found for androidx.camera.core.impl.ImageAnalysisConfig@4370a28.
    at androidx.camera.lifecycle.LifecycleCameraRepository.bindToLifecycleCamera(LifecycleCameraRepository.java:302)
    at androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(ProcessCameraProvider.java:652)
    at androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(ProcessCameraProvider.java:387)

Anyone who knows what could cause this behavior?

Emulator camera has all kinds of issues. I would suggest you trying different emulator if you can. e.g. the profile is Nexus 5X which is known to be problematic even with a real device. Could you try a different profile that is more up to date?

Actually, I changed API level and it started working. I changed it to 31
